# Core Data Delete issue with Swift

Tags: core-data, swift

I am using the following IB Action to delete data from my Core Data and TableView:

```
 //Events
@IBAction func btnDelTask_Click(sender: UIButton){

    let appDel: foodforteethAppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as foodforteethAppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    /*
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Food")

    myList = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    */
    if let tv = tblTasks {

        var bas: NSManagedObject!


        for bas: AnyObject in myList
        {
           context.deleteObject(bas as NSManagedObject)
        }

        myList.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)


        tv.reloadData()
    }

}
```

So when I run this in the simulator and click the button to delete then everything seems fine. The table clears. I can go back and forth through the app to different parts of it and return to the table and everything is still clear.

HOWEVER, if I then restart the simulator (without resetting the content and settings), the rows in the table that were previously deleted, suddenly reappear :/

Why is this happening? I don't think it is actually deleting everything from the Core Data which I've found out by commenting out 'myList.removeAll(keepCapacity:false)' and then it doesn't work even normally and nothing deletes.

Any help?

Comment: It doesn't look like you are saving. You have to save the context.

Comment: Haha oh God do I feel stupid! Thank you!